# e.stopPropogation() Equivalent for Capture Phase of Click Event?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking for a way in JS to stop a click event from continuing down the DOM to a nested child element (capture phase) when the parent element was clicked.

It would be the inverse of the `e.stopPropogation()` function to prevent a click event from bubbling up.

Is there a native JS function for this?

*Edit 03/10*
[Link to example](http://codepen.io/Zacc206/pen/RNeryL)

*Edit 03/11*
Typo in the function call - it's `stopPropagation()`, not `stopPropogation()`. Thanks to @JackPattishall for the find.

Comment: events don't bubble down. If a handler on a child element is triggering, then its because you clicked it.

Comment: `stopPropagation` will also stop an event during the capture phase: http://jsfiddle.net/oc3cec8b/

Comment: @WillReese: They do "bubble down". There's a capturing phase and then a bubbling phase. That's why there's a third argument to `addEventListener`.

Comment: @JackPattishall Hrmm. I was getting a invalid method error when I tried `stopPropogation` on my first go round. Time to put together a fiddle...

Comment: @zacc206 Cool! Hopefully it's just a typographical issue. I know I've used `stopPropagation` in the past with success. Good luck!

Comment: @JackPattishall The error I'm getting is that the event object "Doesn't support" the `stopPropogation` method. [Link to pen](http://codepen.io/Zacc206/pen/RNeryL).

Comment: @zacc206 Ah, you want `stopPropagation` my friend :) (an `a` rather than `o`) - A forked pen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EadPGK

Comment: @JackPattishall Aaah. Thanks, thought I had checked that but I missed it anyhow. I appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

yes there is native js function for capturing event in capture phase.

In all browsers, except IE<9, there are two stages of event processing.

The event first goes down - that’s called capturing, and then bubbles up. This behavior is standartized in W3C specification.

All methods of event handling ignore the caputiring phase. Using addEventListener with last argument true is only the way to catch the event at capturing.

elem.addEventListener( type, handler, phase )

phase = true
    The handler is set on the capturing phase.
phase = false
    The handler is set on the bubbling phase.

For better understanding of event capturing and bubbling you can follow this [link](http://javascript.info/tutorial/bubbling-and-capturing)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I've got a solid grasp of the capture phase, but the only problem is that the click event continues past the parent all the way down to the lowest level child - which I what I hope to prevent. The eventPropogation interrupts the bubble phase, but is there a function that interrupts the capture phase?

Comment: @zacc206: Are your events bound with jQuery? It (unfortunately) uses its own special abstraction over the native event system, and I don't believe they recognize the reality of event capturing.

Comment: @LyeFish I believe so, it's a Kendo UI widget specifically.

Answer (score 0):

okey, One thing you and do is use the stopPropogation() at the top in Dom.

eg. you have a table(#table1) and elements(tr,td).
so, if i do:

```
table1.addEventListener("click",function(event){
  event.stopPropagation();
  console.log(this);
},true);
tableElem[2].addEventListener("click",function(event){
  console.log(this);
});
tableElem[2].addEventListener("click",function(event){
  console.log("hii");
});
```

The event will be intercepted at top and propogation will be stopped.
stopPropogation() stops propagation irrespective of on which step event is intercepted.